# Как узнать значение бита в байте?

Tags: c#, byte

Допустим, у меня есть какой-нибудь байт.
Как мне узнать значение, например, третьего бита в этом байте?

Comment: Сделать AND с соотв. маской да проверить, ноль или не очень. Например...

Comment: @Akina , извините, а можно более примитивно сказать?

Comment: @Dungeon_Master Вы берете ещё один байт (последовательность 11111111), и затем побитово (то есть каждый бит), Вы отправляете на функцию And с битами Вашего байта. Если фукнция and возвращает True значит на этом месте лежит 1, если False значит 0

Comment: @artemgh Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Akina И вам тоже спасибо!

Comment: @Dungeon_Master вернее даже, если у Вас получится, Вы можете сразу вытащить этот бит и проверить его одного с единицей

Comment: `((myByte >> 3) & 1) == 1`